# Installing kali linux 2017.1 to dual boot

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multi-boot, kali-linux

I'm trying to dual boot my computer to windows and kali linux. I have a bootable USB key and everytime i try to install it it says something like "can't get data from CD-ROM"
I've tried using 2 usb keys (both bootable and 1 bootable 1 just having the ISO) i've tried un-plugging and plugging back in the USB key after 30 seconds and i've tried mounting the files to a cd-rom but nothing works.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  That being said, have you considered running Linux as a virtual machine inside one of the free hypervisors you can use within Windows 10, such as VirtualBox or Hyper-V?  To be honest, we see a **lot** of questions in the Super User realm authored by people who encounter problems while they attempt to dual-boot Windows and Linux... *especially* Kali.

Comment: @Run5k my laptop isn't powerful enough to run a virtual machine and dual booting makes it easier to use and less distracting, and booting to a USB key isn't a good choice for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well.

**My solution:** I used a USB with the ISO extracted into it. When I got the error simply unplugging the USB and placing it back into the same USB port, then asking it to try again solved the problem for me.

**Another route** You could boot your computer into windows and run the setup.exe located on your flash drive. It will start the installation process in Windows, will reboot, and you can continue the installation process after the reboot. It will come up to a screen allowing you to continue the installation or boot into windows--choose continue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has introduced various new features at boot with Win8 and Win10 (namely: UEFI and Secure Boot) these have been known to create a multitude of issues when attempting to install Linux along-side an existing Windows OS. To install from a bootable USB, a few elements in your BIOS should be disabled as they could be the culprits responsible for your problems. I would recommend that you apply the following changes to your BIOS:

1. **Disable** "Secure Boot" and/or "Quick Boot".
2. **Disable** UEFI boot,  and **Enable** "Legacy Boot" instead.

After these changes have been made to your BIOS configuration, plug the USB key back in, and reboot.

N.B: I am assuming that you have already changed the order of your boot devices and that USB is the first one on the list. If not, you must do that as well (this is also accessible in your BIOS configuration options).

Regards,
Mike